# Implicit conversion to/from an enum

Tags: c++, c, enums, implicit-conversion

This is a basic question which I hoped to Google easily, but didn't find an answer for.

Let's say that I have an enum:

```
enum abc { a, b, c };
```

What are the supported implicit conversions? Are there any compiler extensions or different behavior between compilers?

I'm asking about implicit conversion to an enum:

```
enum abc test = (** which type can appear here? **);
```

As well as implicit conversion from an enum:

```
(** which type can appear here? **) test2 = test;
```

I'd like to know the answer for both C and C++.

Comment: You should make your question more specific, it's interesting. But you know that *which type can appear here?* is `int`, right?

Comment: @iharob is it always the case? http://ideone.com/5WvR9K ... that's why I'm asking

Comment: @iharob Cannot `short` or `signed char` or `_Bool` or `double` values in range like `1e2`?

Comment: @chux if they are convertible to `int` I guess, Yes!.

Comment: I doubt that the answer is different for C vs. C++, but if they are which would you prefer to know?

Comment: @MarkRansom the code that I have linked compiles in C, so they seem to be different. I'd prefer to see the whole picture, but if you want to answer on one of them, perhaps someone else will do the other.

Answer (score 4):

As the reference says:

> Values of unscoped enumeration type are implicitly-convertible to integral types

[Reference link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum)

Comment: This is c++ only, at least the reference is. The answer perhaps apply to both, but you should probably make that clear here. Specially if the reference says so.

Comment: For C:
"Each enumerated type shall be compatible with char,asigned integer type, or an
unsigned integer type. The choice of type is implementation-defined,110) but shall be
capable of representing the values of all the members of the enumeration"

Comment: The converse is not true though, you have to add explicit cast.